# i want to create app where users can see polyline between markers and when clicked on marker should see image that are stored in my json

Tags: react-native

when i use image inside  i get error index=5 count=2 can anyone help i want to create ployline between markers and when user clicks on marker they should get ployine and image but i am getting polyline but when i use  i get error index=5 count=2 and app crashes[enter image description here][1]

//explorescreen.js code

```
    import React from 'react';
    import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
    import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
    import { View, Text, Dimensions, Animated, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';
    import Polyline from '@mapbox/polyline';
    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('screen')
    const locations = require('../locations')
    export default class ExploreScreen extends React.Component {
        state = {
            latitude: null,
            longitude: null,
            locations: locations,
            direct: false
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            this.GetLocations();
        }
        GetLocations = async () => {
            Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                ({ coords: { latitude, longitude } }) => this.setState({ latitude, longitude }, this.mergeCoords),
                (error) => console.log('Error:', error)
            )
            const { locations: [sampleLocation] } = this.state
            this.setState({
                desLatitude: sampleLocation.coords.latitude,
                desLongitude: sampleLocation.coords.longitude,
            }, this.mergeCoords)
        }
        mergeCoords = () => {
            const { latitude, longitude, desLatitude, desLongitude } = this.state
            const hasStartAndEnd = (latitude !== null && desLatitude !== null)
            // if the line have start and end 
            if (hasStartAndEnd) {
                const concatStart = `${latitude},${longitude}`
                const concatEnd = `${desLatitude},${desLongitude}`
                this.getDirections(concatStart, concatEnd)
            }
        }
        async getDirections(startLoc, desLoc) {
            try {
                const resp = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${startLoc}&destination=${desLoc}&key=AIzaSyDoWUeYVrFse7r76yOMX9dAMgelIlNVGSY`)
                const resJson = await resp.json();
    
                const points = Polyline.decode(resJson.routes[0].overview_polyline.points);
                const coords = points.map(point => {
                    return {
                        latitude: point[0],
                        longitude: point[1]
                    }
                })
                this.setState({ coords, direct: true })
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('Error: ', err)
            }
        }
        onMarkerPress = location => () => {
            const { coords: { latitude, longitude } } = location
            this.setState({
                destination: location,
                desLatitude: latitude,
                desLongitude: longitude
            }, this.mergeCoords)
        }
        renderMarkers = () => {
            const { locations } = this.state
            return (
                <View>
                    {
                        locations.map((location, index) => {
                            const {
                                coords: { latitude, longitude }
                            } = location
                            return (
                                <MapView.Marker
                                    key={index}
                                    coordinate={{ latitude, longitude }}
                                    onPress={this.onMarkerPress(location)}>
                                    <Animated.View style={[styles.markerWrap]}>
                                        <Animated.Image
                                            source={require('../assests/images/marker.png')}
                                            style={styles.marker}
                                            resizeMode="cover" />
                                    </Animated.View>
                                </MapView.Marker>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </View>
            )
        }
        render() {
            const { latitude, longitude, coords, destination } = this.state
            if (latitude) {
                return (
                    <MapView
                        showsUserLocation
                        style={{ flex: 1 }}
                        initialRegion={{
                            latitude,
                            longitude,
                            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                            userLocationPriority: 'high',
                            userLocationFastestInterval: 8000,
                        }}
                    >
                        {this.renderMarkers()}
                        {this.state.direct &&
                            <MapView.Polyline
                                strokeWidth={2}
                                strokeColor="purple"
                                coordinates={coords}
                            />
                        }
                        <Image
                            source={{ uri: destination && destination.image_url }}
                            style={{
                                flex: 1,
                                width: width * 0.95,
                                alignSelf: 'center',
                                height: height * 0.15,
                                position: 'absolute',
                                bottom: height * 0.05
                            }}
                        />
                    </MapView>
                );
            }
    
            return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Text>We need your permissions !!</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }[enter image description here][1]
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        markerWrap: {
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
        }, marker: {
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
        },
    })
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiO3g.png
```